# C# Crystal report change print dialog options

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, desktop-application, crystal-reports-2010

1) I want to change the options in print dialog which is default dialog of crystal report.
2) I want to show only the default printer name. And not allow user to change the printer.
3) I want to show from page and to page option.

and hide all other options. 
Can I do that?

Please reply.

Comment: Is this a web application or a desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

One way could be simply show the printer name in message box/your own form as dialog box and Call the

```
  rpt.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 5, 6);
```

Comment: And how to allow user to enter page from & to page?

Comment: @faheemkhan on print dialog box, if  user entered 3 copies. then it prints only 1 copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up you print options and call [ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691452%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to print to the default printer. In the print options, if you set the printer name to "Default", it will print to your default printer.

In terms of entering from/to page, you should define your own form that will allow the user to enter a value for each. Or if you want to force them to print all pages, you can use this to get the number of pages to print.

```
    var pageView = (PageView) crystalReportViewer1.Controls[0];
    var numberOfPages = pageView.GetLastPageNumber();
```